# Android Emulator stuck loading screen on M1 mac/ Apple Silicon

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-developers-console

I had downloaded Android Studio on my M1 MacBook air but I can't run the emulator and it just gives me an error. I search Android Studio requirements for mac and it says that it requires mac os 10.10 or higher and a minimum of 2 GB disk space and 4GB of ram. Anyone have this issue and how do I solve it?

I try download the arm image android studio it is stuck on the loading screen for the emulator.

[image]

Comment: is it resolved?

Comment: Nope, I still cannot run the emulator on android studio, I only can code but cannot run

Comment: even if it ran, performance would be terrible with just 8gb, despite the claim that macbookair is "faster than 98%" (calculators?)

Comment: Actually it is faster than my bro macbook pro 8GB of ram, his suffer alot

Comment: I couldn't find any issues in Google's issue tracker regarding adding support for this, so I filed one. Please star it, I would love to see this support too.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173766929

Comment: Hi! 

Would u recommend to buy m1 air to develop androd app? 
Or it's better to wait some time?

Comment: @YaSi Hi! I would recommend u to wait for a while cause right now android emulator cannot run on m1 mac, but if u have an android phone and the emulator is not an issue for you then go ahead cause the m1 Mac is really fast, faster than the previous-gen MacBook and IMac and some of the intel and AMD pc/desktop

Comment: Have u faced any problem with running Android Studio on m1? 
Have u tried Visual Studio?
The emulator issue is clear.

Comment: @YaSi Did not face any issue running Android Studio on m1 Mac, I am able to download and run android studio, no forced stop of app face till now but sadly I only can code cannot run emulator :(    The same goes for visual studio, it downloads and runs very smoothly

Comment: @YaSi Opening the app was very fast too, only the first time usage it takes a longer time to open cause the app need to use Rosetta 2 to convert

Comment: @ryantay 
I Will not cancel my apple order. Thanx a lot.

Comment: @YaSi How's your m1 Mac?

Comment: I'm excited.
If I launch android studio it will get warmer after some time. 
Compiling time is twice less than on my previous intel i7 mac book

Comment: @YaSi cause android studio is not build to run on m1 mac, it is still currently in beta

Answer (score 46):

As for now (19/11/2020) any of the Virtualization tools do not work with the new Apple M1 macs. So things like docker, emulators etc. We might have to wait a bit until this is fully supported unfortunately.

Comment: IDK why this got downvoted this is the correct answer...

Comment: Docker has recently released its M1 version. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-m1/

Comment: This is the wrong answer, Emulator is working since 7th December 2020 https://stackoverflow.com/a/65176907/1079990

Answer (score 33):

Good news !

**Edit on 28th July 2021**

> Apple Silicon Support

There is an **arm64** release version available for **Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1)**
You can download it here https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

When NDK runs into `Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64` you can solve it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69540773/1079990)

End of beta ! Thank you

**Edit on March 2021**

I can confirm, this preview of Emulator works properly
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/12/android-emulator-apple-silicon-preview.html

In the blog there is a link to a [private repo](https://github.com/741g/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases) (2021-Jan-04). They moved repo to google and there you find V3 https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases

Since v3 even audio-out works (no audio-in)

**Edit on 4th Feb 2021**

Now audio in and out works properly https://github.com/741g/android-emulator-m1-preview/issues/10#issuecomment-773532762

**Edit March 2021**

You can simply use one of them and it's working out of the box

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you running this on M1 also?

Comment: When I understand the question right: of course, it's from my M1

Comment: Keep attention: the repo was moved, I updated my post

Comment: @hannesach, try the beta version but it is still very laggy, takes ages to turn on the emulator, hopefully, they fix that issue.

Comment: My emulator on M1 starts very fast. At least faster then on my x86 old mac @ryantay

Comment: IC, not sure why mine is slow tho

Comment: In case if it's not working for someone. Try using "Profiler" and add your app in that. "Profiler" of android studio.

Comment: how about at now ? maret 2022 its consume 4GB memory/ram , its very lagging on mbpm1 can use emulator.

Comment: @YogiArifWidodo hwat do you mean ? Your question is too much unspecific

Comment: i mean can you update your answer just for FYI about the emulator just for more description/test/feel after using the emulator on m 1. if you can.

Answer (score 8):

On August release notes you can see on the emulator for Arm host section an entry where they said the support for M1 is in progress.
Check the link below:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#emulator_for_arm64_hosts

Answer (score 2):

As of today the android emulator is up and working on the Apple Silicon here's a working demo from a googler

[image]

source: https://twitter.com/GoogleLfy/status/1332474914398322689
And the known issues here:  https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/12/android-emulator-apple-silicon-preview.html

we can expect the stable release by the end of 2020
here's a conversation about the same https://www.reddit.com/user/lfy_google/

Answer (score 2):

Android studio has still not released a modified version for M1 macs, the version you are running, was originally made for intel chips, and is running via rosetta2. And rosetta does not support virtualisation, so you cant run emulator, but you could do all else coding stuff with minor bugs, for testing your code you may use a physical android device and it works just fine...please let me know if further problem exists...

Comment: There is a beta preview of android studio tho

Answer (score 2):

This is the working emulator done by Android developers https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview
it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

**For other ARM devices**, it should be involved as an Instruction Set problem, in that case you can go to the AVD Manager of your AS and when create new virtual device, make sure to download the system image with arm64-v8a ABI, which is shown as bellow.

[image]

**For Mac M1 chip**, these arm64 images can not solve the problem and for now the best way is to wait Google release the compatible images.

Comment: Any idea why these don't show up in Android Studio. This page is blank when I go to it?

Comment: How about under the Recommended tag?

Comment: I run the emulator that you ask me to download, the emulator appears, but it keeps on saying asking target devices to come online and can't bring me to the home page

Comment: You can try wiping data of the virtual device by right click it in AVD Manager, then rerun the project. Also check the Android Emulator box in  SDK Manager -> SDK Tools

Comment: @PatrickGeng Are you actually able to run the emulator on an M1 machine with this image, or are you speculating?

Comment: No error - it's just stuck like on the screenshot in the question. Guess we'll just have to wait a bit until they support the m1.

Comment: yup, arm images don't work, i download arm image and it just stuck on the loading screen as shown from my screenshot above

Answer (score 1):

I heard that the emulator won't work due to arm architecture of the apple silicon. Using a phone for debugging might be the only option. I also heard that android studio were working on an update for the M1.

Comment: Hmm, I search android developers website they never talk about supporting for m1 MacBook, I email google but none of them reply me, such bad customer support, really wish there is the documentation for how to solve or support for m1 macbook

Comment: Given the Arm64 Mac machine is just released, it may take quite a while for google to make its softwares fully compatible to the new platform

Comment: Ic, but there should be an announcement make on the website for developers to see

Comment: Where to find any news for android studio on arm mac?

Comment: @ryantay On Reddit, one of the developers replied to a post that they know the issue and they are working on an update.

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar Do you have the link? i went to android developers website and no news about support for m1 and I also went to android studio website and the same thing happen, no news about m1 support

Comment: @ryantay check the first comment: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/jrt7ph/armbased_macs_for_android_development/

Answer (score 1):

There is a rudenmentary beta of the emulator for Mac M1 here
[github link](https://github.com/741g/android-emulator-m1-preview)

Answer (score 1):

android studio have made a rough initial preview of the emulator running on Apple Silicon.More details are available in this link below

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/12/android-emulator-apple-silicon-preview.html

Also you can download DMG file from GitHub:
https://github.com/741g/android-emulator-m1-preview

Answer (score 1):

Android has released beta emulator for M1 chipset

Please check this think to beta release

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/12/android-emulator-apple-silicon-preview.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Android Studio only supports the HAXM Intel version (which isn't compatible with ARM processors) of virtualization, to run the emulator. But maybe in the coming weeks they might release the compatible versions for apple silicon processors. Till then the only option is to use a physical device.

Answer (score 1):

there is an Android Emulator Apple Silicon Preview in the next documentation
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/12/android-emulator-apple-silicon-preview.html

Answer (score 1):

On my M1 machine, the emulator would get stuck ( not open ) and the dock icon would say 'qemu-system-aarch64' and then that was it.

I managed to get the emulator to start by running it via the terminal and  adding the gpu host flag

```
emulator -gpu host -avd Pixel_5_API_32
```

P.S. I couldn't find the right stack issue, so I'm leaving this here.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the new M1 chips run on arm Architecture and not x86.
You have to download the arm compatible virtual devices those are available in the other images tab inorder to run those emulators.

Also try this:

1. Wipe data of the virtual device by right clicking it in AVD Manager, then rerun the project.
2. Check the Android Emulator box in SDK Manager -> SDK Tools

Comment: yes, i downloaded arm image, but it just stuck on the loading screen as seen from my screenshot above

Answer (score 0):

Download the android-emulator-m1-preview.dmg from
https://github.com/741g/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases