# Android NDK Apple SiliconM1 run into: Unknown host CPU architecture arm64

Tags: android, android-ndk, apple-m1, apple-silicon

There are two kinds to build Android with NDK

### cmake

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "../sharedCode/CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

This works fine with Apple Silicon M1

### ndk-build

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
    }
}
```

On a Apple Silicon M1 I run into

```
Unknown host CPU architecture arm64
```

The question is to solve this ?

Comment: getting same error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541831/unknown-host-cpu-architecture-arm64-android-ndk-siliconm1-apple-macbook-pro

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi did you see my answer ? Option C is working fine !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve this on a Apple Silicon M1 I found three options

### A

Use NDK 24

```
android {
    ndkVersion "24.0.8215888"
    ...
}
```

You can install it with

```
echo "y" | sudo ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install 'ndk;24.0.8215888' 1>/dev/null
```

### B

convert your `ndk-build` into a `cmake` build

### C

Change your `ndk-build` to use Rosetta x86. Search for your installed ndk with

```
find ~ -name ndk-build 2>/dev/null
```

eg

```
vi ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/ndk-build
```

and change

```
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
$DIR/build/ndk-build "$@"
```

to

```
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
arch -x86_64 $DIR/build/ndk-build "$@"
```

### D

Use a x86 Android Studio version. But this is slow

[image]

Comment: "A" doesn't work for me, I'm getting `NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema`

Comment: @massivemadness For me it works properly on a M1 https://github.com/hannesa2/panoramagl/pull/137/files