# Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64 , Android NDK SiliconM1 Apple MacBook Pro

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, arm64, apple-m1

I've got a project that is working fine in windows os but when I switched my laptop and opened an existing project in **MacBook Pro M1**. I'm unable to run an existing android project in **MacBook pro M1**. first I was getting

> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDevDebugKotlin'. > A failure
> occurred while executing
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution    >
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

this error was due to the Room database I applied a fix that was adding below library before Room database and also **changed my JDK location from file structure from JRE to JDK.**

> kapt "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0"

```
   //Room components
    kapt "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"
```

after that now I'm getting an issue which is **Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64**

there is an SDK in my project that is using this below line.

```
android {
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
           path 'Android.mk'
        }
    }
    ndkVersion '21.4.7075529'


}
```

**App Gradle**

```
 externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.18.1"
            //version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
```

> [CXX1405] error when building with ndkBuild using
> /Users/mac/Desktop/Consumer-Android/ime/dictionaries/jnidictionaryv2/Android.mk:
> Build command failed. Error while executing process
> /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/ndk-build with
> arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
> APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/Users/mac/Desktop/Consumer-Android/ime/dictionaries/jnidictionaryv2/Android.mk
> APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1
> APP_PLATFORM=android-21
> NDK_OUT=/Users/mac/Desktop/Consumer-Android/ime/dictionaries/jnidictionaryv2/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/4k4s2lc6/obj
> NDK_LIBS_OUT=/Users/mac/Desktop/Consumer-Android/ime/dictionaries/jnidictionaryv2/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/4k4s2lc6/lib
> APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n} ERROR:
> Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64

which is causing this issue and whenever I comment on this line

> path 'Android.mk'

it starts working fine, is there any way around which will help me run this project with this piece of code without getting this NDK issue?

**Update** - It seems that Room got fixed in the latest updates, Therefore you may consider updating Room to the latest version **(2.3.0-alpha01 / 2.4.0-alpha03 or above)**

**use ndkVersion "24.0.8215888" update ndk to this version and no need to edit any script :)**

[GitHub Issue Tracker](https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard/issues/3026)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

solved this issue.

Finder -> Go To Folder(/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529)
-> now edit **ndk-build** open it in text editor and paste below code script and re-run your project.

**from**

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
$DIR/build/ndk-build "$@"
```

**to**

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash $DIR/build/ndk-build "$@"
```

[Reference Link](https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1299)

Comment: worked like a charm

Comment: If you don't find the Library folder in /Users/{username}/. Press Cmd + Shift +"." to show hidden folders

Comment: I tried this but then I'm getting "Cause: error=1, Operation not permitted" while building project and build failes

Comment: update your idk to latest version and then check.. @DanishAnsari

Comment: after changing ndk-build file, my M1 Pro shows that file is corrupted or damaged when opening.

Comment: @VivekMangal re-install ndk then and try again check if its works or not.?

Comment: same error after re-installing

Comment: I figured out that TextEdit messes up the file and corrupts it, so better edit the file directly in Android Studio or VS Code or any editor of your choice other than TextEdit

Comment: Thanks. It worked after editing with xcode.

Comment: bravo,  man,  bravo

Comment: i have the same issue but couldn't implement that solution for android-ndk-r10e. is there a way to handle this?

Comment: @HakanErbaş paste your error here..

Comment: This worked but only after I installed Rosseta. Open a terminal and run: softwareupdate --install-rosetta

Answer (score 34):

To solve this on a Apple Silicon M1 I found three options

### A

Use NDK 24

```
android {
    ndkVersion "24.0.8215888"
    ...
}
```

You can install it with

```
echo "y" | sudo ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install 'ndk;24.0.8215888'
```

or

```
echo "y" | sudo ${ANDROID_HOME}/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --install 'ndk;24.0.8215888'
```

Depending what where `sdkmanager` is located [image]

### B

Change your `ndk-build` to use Rosetta x86. Search for your installed ndk with

```
find ~ -name ndk-build 2>/dev/null
```

eg

```
vi ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/ndk-build
```

and change

```
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
$DIR/build/ndk-build "$@"
```

to

```
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash $DIR/build/ndk-build "$@"
```

[image]

### C

convert your `ndk-build` into a `cmake` build

Comment: "$@ is missing closing quotations at the end

Comment: A for OS X:
#: sudo [AndroidSDK folder]/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --install 'ndk;24.0.7956693' --channel=3. The latest cmdline-tools should be installed via AS package manager.

Comment: See my answer, point A @oxied

Comment: Your A doesn't work for me. My A — works.