# Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64 2022 Macbook Air M1

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, apple-m1

I cannot resolve this error, even though it is mentioned as resolved here in M1.

[Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64 , Android NDK SiliconM1 Apple MacBook Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541831/unknown-host-cpu-architecture-arm64-android-ndk-siliconm1-apple-macbook-pro)

My error code.

[CXX1405] error when building with ndkBuild using /Users/adamheinrich/Desktop/android-solocoo-2.0/Solocoo/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk: Build command failed.
Error while executing process /Users/adamheinrich/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.1.5948944/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/Users/adamheinrich/Desktop/android-solocoo-2.0/Solocoo/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/Users/adamheinrich/Desktop/android-solocoo-2.0/Solocoo/app/src/main/jni/Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-22 NDK_OUT=/Users/adamheinrich/Desktop/android-solocoo-2.0/Solocoo/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/x2j681s3/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/Users/adamheinrich/Desktop/android-solocoo-2.0/Solocoo/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/x2j681s3/lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
ERROR: Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64

After editing ndk-build with text editor I have.
[image]

What else can I do?
How can I install .dmg beta ndk? It is not available in SDK Manager via Android Studio.

Also after editing this file my OS says it is corrupted/ damaged. How can I edit it properly?

Comment: In answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69541958/150978 it is mentioned that one solution is to switch to NDK 24 but you are still using 20.1.5948944. So only in v24 this issue had been solved.

Comment: I cannot build gradle with 24.

Comment: Then use on of the other fixes mentioned in the linked answer.

Comment: Using sublime text to edit the file was the solution. I was not able to do that with Mac OS text editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Sublime Text editor instead of Macbook text editor allowed me to edit it without corrupting it.  Edit `ndk-build` file in Library/Android/sdk/ndk
to:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash $DIR/build/ndk-build "$@"
```

Comment: `ndk-build` is large file of almost 350 lines. Where exactly to add this above snippet?? @GigaCoder