# Cause: error=1, Operation not permitted showing after modifying NDK build file for fixing CPU architecture: arm64 issue on M1 Apple MacBook Pro

Tags: android-ndk, apple-m1, apple-silicon

Once I got the following error :

> Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64

, Android NDK Silicon M1 Apple MacBook Pro

I did the following solution from stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69555276/18491169):

*Finder -> Go To Folder(/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529) -> now edit ndk-build open it in text editor and paste below code script and re-run your project.*

from

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
$DIR/build/ndk-build "$@"
```

to

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash $DIR/build/ndk-build "$@"
```

**After this NDK build file modification, I'm getting another error saying :**

> Cause: error=1, Operation not permitted

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also getting same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem (`Cause: error=1, Operation not permitted`) by re-installing NDK. In my case, I used a different version of the old NDK (`16.1.4479499`).

1. uninstall NDK
   Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools
   uncheck "NDK (side by side)"
   click "Apply"
2. reinstall NDK
   check "NDK (side by side)" again
   click "Apply"
3. copy old NDK to `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/16.1.4479499`
4. edit `ndk-build` again
5. build again