# Apple Silicon not being able to run Apps in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, arm64, apple-silicon

I have M1Max Apple Macbook Pro (Apple Silicon chip).

Trying to run Android apps on emulator in Android Studio.

I tried the following emulators:

- Pixel 5 API 32, Android API 32 arm64 (this launches but can't run
  app)
- Pixel 3a API 32 arm 64 (launches but can't run app)
- Pixel XL API 30, Android 11.0, x86 (this won't even launch)

When I try to run app in any of them I get the following error:

```
[CXX1405] error when building with ndkBuild using xxxxxx/Android.mk: Build command failed.
Error while executing process /xxxxxx/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null 
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/Users/xxxxx/Android.mk
NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/Users/xxxxx/Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a 
NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1
APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=/xxxxx/obj
NDK_LIBS_OUT=/xxxxx/lib
APP_CFLAGS+=-DLITE_VERSION=1 APP_CFLAGS+=-DDEBUG=1 
NDK_DEBUG:=1 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
ERROR: Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64
```

It seems it boils down to this problem:
**ERROR: Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64**

What solution should I see to be able to run this on Apple silicon?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64 , Android NDK SiliconM1 Apple MacBook Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541831/unknown-host-cpu-architecture-arm64-android-ndk-siliconm1-apple-macbook-pro)

Comment: You have the solution to your problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541831/unknown-host-cpu-architecture-arm64-android-ndk-siliconm1-apple-macbook-pro/69555276

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error does not have anything with the emulator and your M1 arm processor. You need to define NDK path in your project.

```
NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
```

Install NDK from SDK manager and check if the project runs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to solve the issue. I installed all NDK's and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you update all the paths where your NDK is installed?